# How to reconfigure the cluster in CDH5?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have been able to successfully install and start the cloudera CDH5 server and manager and all the core projects along with that, viz. HDFS, HUE, HIVE etc. However recently I deleted the temporary hdfs directory (/dfs/*) and then formatted the namenode due to certain issues. Now I find all new sorts of issues which I am not able solve.
Some are given as below:

1. The problem with hue,

[image: Hue issue]

2. The problem with HDFS,

[image: HDFS issue]

Any help would highly be appreciated.
Thanking in advance.

Edit: I have tried creating all those missing directories in both HDFS as well as local FS and have tried various owners for them to without success.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me, being the most easy solution, is deleting all those services from the cloudera web manager and readding them back.